# How to turn axis labels into shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add boxes to replace the Y axis labels, such as in this figure. [image]

I'm using ggplot but any other R package would work too.

```
input <- data.frame(
  Pre.Subtype=c("Basal sq.", "Basal Sq.", "Basal sq.", "Neuronal", "Luminal", "Luminal", "Luminal"), 
  Post.Subtype=c("Basal sq.", "No tumor", "Luminal inf.", "Basal sq.", "Luminal", "Luminal pap.", "No tumor"), 
  Number.of.Patients=c(2,3,4,5,2,4,4), Percentage=c(34,23,23,53,20,34,56))

ggplot(data=input, aes(x=Pre.Subtype, y=Percentage, fill=Post.Subtype)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme( axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, colour="black"), axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold")) + 
  labs(x= "Pre", y="Percentage", title="Post") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Number.of.Patients), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=0.5, hjust=-0.3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#fed976", "#7fcdbb", "#4d004b", "grey"), name="") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=20), axis.text.x = element_text(size=13, face="bold", colour="black")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold", size=16), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `clip = "off"` in `coord_flip` as well as ensuring the y limit doesn't drop below zero:

```r
... + coord_flip(ylim = c(0,50), clip = "off") + ...
```

Now you can draw a `geom_rect` outside of the plot area:

```r
... + geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.55, xmax = 0.85, ymin = -10, ymax = -7), 
                fill = "blue", size = 2, colour = "darkblue")
```

Which looks something like this:

[image]

Or use a `geom_label`:

```r
geom_label(aes(label = "2", x = 0.55, y = -7), fill = "blue", size = 5, colour = "white")
```

Like this:

[image]

Of course, you'll need to add multiple geoms to get this effect for each category.

Answer (score 1):

For a more automated way to do this, I suggest generating two separate plots, and combining them using ggarrange as shown below.

I have also fixed an issue where different bars were showing up in different widths in your original code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
input <- data.frame(
  Pre.Subtype=c("Basal sq.", "Basal Sq.", "Basal sq.", "Neuronal", "Luminal", "Luminal", "Luminal"), 
  Post.Subtype=c("Basal sq.", "No tumor", "Luminal inf.", "Basal sq.", "Luminal", "Luminal pap.", "No tumor"), 
  Number.of.Patients=c(2,3,4,5,2,4,4), Percentage=c(34,23,23,53,20,34,56))

p1 <- ggplot(data=input, aes(x=Pre.Subtype, y=Percentage, fill=Post.Subtype)) + 
  #geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")) + 
  theme_classic() +
  theme( axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.title.x=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold")) + 
  labs(x= "Pre", y="Percentage", title="Post") + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Number.of.Patients), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=0.5, hjust=-0.3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#fed976", "#7fcdbb", "#4d004b", "grey", "red"), name="") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=20), axis.text.x = element_text(size=13, face="bold", colour="black")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face="bold", size=16), axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  coord_flip() 


p2 <- ggplot(data=input, aes(x=Pre.Subtype, y=Percentage)) + 
  theme_void() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  geom_label(data = (input %>% group_by(Pre.Subtype) %>% 
                       summarise_at(c('Number.of.Patients'),sum)), aes(label=Number.of.Patients, y = -0.1), fill = 'blue', color = 'white') +  
  coord_flip() + labs(title = 'Pre') + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,-1,0,0), "cm"))

ggarrange(p2,p1, widths = c(0.1,0.9), align = "h")
```

This will give you the picture below.

[image]